# Error when sending data between connected devices in Game Center

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit

I am working on a local multiplayer, real time game in swift 5. In order to achieve the real time gameplay, I am sending data back and forth between two devices with the function `GKMatch.sendData(data:, to:, withDataSendingMethod:)`. It works fairly inconsistently, regardless of if I use `.reliable` or `.unreliable`, however the error it gives me when it is unable to send data *is* consistent. It is as follow:

`2020-07-27 21:07:22.433631-0400 Teacher Brawl[19336:5244039] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] AGPSessionRecvFrom:1954 0x103f11600 sack: SEARCH FAILURE SERIAL NUMBER (0000000B) FROM (5682ABEE)...`

Where Teacher Brawl is the name of the project.

I was wondering if anyone is able to provide insight as to why I am getting the error, as I do not fully understand it being relatively new to swift and newer to GameKit. The code I am using to send the data is shown below, and it is being called anytime there is a tap on the screen, which in the context of this game is fairly minimal. If you need any further details please let me know, I would be happy to provide them. All help is greatly appreciated as the inconsistency of data sending has stopped any progress I can make for this game. :)

```
func sendButtons(button: String) {
        let sendableString: Data? = button.data(using: .utf8)
        do {
            try localMatch.send(sendableString!, to: localMatch.players, dataMode: .unreliable)
        }
        catch {
            print("")
        }
        
        
    }
```

For reference, the variable `localMatch` is my variable for the `GKMatch` that was returned when both players joined the game.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is common and shouldn't interfere with your game sending data. My app gets this error but still sends data fine.

If you are sending data to all players, you should use the built in function `func sendData(toAllPlayers data: Data, with mode: GKMatch.SendDataMode) throws`. You should also send data reliably if it is not being sent very often. For debugging reasons, you might want to print when data is sent and print errors. Here is the full code you can try.

```
func sendButtons(button: String) {
    let sendableString: Data? = button.data(using: .utf8)
    do {
        try localMatch.sendData(toAllPlayers: sendableString!, with: .reliable)
        print("Data sent")
    }
    catch {
        print("Data not sent")
        print(error)
    }
    
    
}
```

If the data is not sent, check if "Data sent" is printed and check for errors